# Get human readable name for Mac model on Ventura

Tags: swift

I have used the following code for get the model identifier of a Mac computer:

```
public static var modelIdentifier: String {
  var size = 0
  sysctlbyname("hw.model", nil, &size, nil, 0)
  var machine = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(size))
  sysctlbyname("hw.model", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
        
  return String(cString: machine)
}
```

This model identifier is used in this variable to get a human readable name of the device:

```
public static var marketingModel: String {
  guard let currentIdentifier = NSLocale.current.languageCode else { return String.hyphen }

  let modelIdentifier = self.modelIdentifier

  var path = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerInformation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/"
  path += currentIdentifier + ".lproj"
  path += "/SIMachineAttributes.plist"

  if let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path) {
    if let plistContents = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: fileData, format: nil)
      as? [String: Any]
    {
      if let contents = plistContents[modelIdentifier] as? [String: Any],
        let localizable = contents["_LOCALIZABLE_"] as? [String: String]
      {
        let marketingModel = localizable["marketingModel"] ?? String.hyphen

        return marketingModel
      }
    }
  }

  return String.hyphen
}
```

This returned strings like `MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)`. However, on the latest MacOS Ventura build, no string is returned for Mac Mac Studio (Mac13,1).
Is there another way to get this string? Do I have to look in a different plist?

Comment: Did you check whether the plist contains the model at all? If not you could file a bug.

Comment: I checked and the plist does not contain the model.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the IORegistryExplorer and found a key that contains this information.

By running the following code in a playground, you can extract the name:

```
import Cocoa
import IOKit

let mainEntry = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMainPortDefault, "IOService:/AppleARMPE/product")
let property = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(mainEntry, "product-description" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)

if let bytes = property?.takeRetainedValue() as? Data
{
    let array = [UInt8](bytes)
    
    let terminatedModelString = String(cString: array)
    
    Swift.print(terminatedModelString)
}

IOObjectRelease(mainEntry)
```

The key suggests that this will only work for Apple Silicon based machines. For Intel based machines, you can still use the code from my initial question.

Comment: Great discovery!. Two suggestions: If you use `takeRetainedValue` Swift takes care of the release. And you can avoid the `[UInt8]` detour with `let modelString = String(data: bytes.dropLast(), encoding: .utf8)!`

Comment: I have changed the code. However, I noticed that the strings in the IORegistry are sometimes null terminated and sometimes they are not. So before calling dropLast(), I would at least check if the string is in fact null terminated. I had a couple of crashes because of some similar code in the past.

Comment: Actually if you get `Data` back then it's a C-String. A check for a trailing zero byte is less expensive than the double conversion.